# Terraform Registry Lambda Module: role_name vs lambda_role?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-modules

When using [the AWS Lambda module from the Terraform Registry](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/lambda/aws/latest), what is the difference between [`lambda_role`](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-lambda#input_lambda_role) and [`role_name`](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-lambda#input_role_name)?

Do they both refer to the lambda's [execution role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-intro-execution-role.html)?  Based on the documentation (included below), it seems like the only difference is that one is a name and one is an ARN.  Is that the only difference?

From the current docs:

- `role_name`:

  - > Name of IAM role to use for Lambda Function.
- `lambda_role`:

  - > IAM role ARN attached to the Lambda Function. This governs both who / what can invoke your Lambda Function, as well as what resources our Lambda Function has access to. See Lambda Permission Model for more details.

Comment: From what I can understand, the `role_name` is used only to assign a name to the IAM role that will allow Lambda to perform different actions (e.g., logging, tracing, sending event information to DLQs). The `lambda_role` is actually the execution role. The code is also set up in a way that if you set the role name than that one is used and if not, it is created based on the value of `lambda_role`. Relevant lines in code: https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-lambda/blob/master/iam.tf#L93 and https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-lambda/blob/master/main.tf#L27.

Comment: @MarkoE If you add that as an answer, I will accept it. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can understand, the `role_name` is used only to assign a name to the IAM role that will allow Lambda to perform different actions (e.g., logging, tracing, sending event information to DLQs). The `lambda_role` is actually the execution role. The code is also set up in a way that if you set the role name than that one is used and if not, it is created based on the value of lambda_role. Relevant lines in code:

- When `create_role` is true, a new role is created, and when it is false, no role is created and the ARN in `lambda_role` is used: https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-lambda/blob/master/main.tf#L27
- When a new role is created, its name is set to `role_name`: https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-lambda/blob/master/iam.tf#L93